# React MUI DataGrid dynamic width with flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have simplified my issue, in order to remove complexity and include the sandbox link. The issue is, when I use flex in columns for distributing space accordingly, it doesn't work, once the page is enlarged (on button click), it doesn't go back to its initial state. Using width fix the issue, I tried to rerender the componenet, just to check, it didn't work either. I am looking for a solution with DataGrid, that whill dynamically and proportionally allocate the space accordingly.
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-dn8qll?file=/index.js)

I have tried rerendering the component, even thoough I think it is not a solution but it still didn't work.